# Datepicker on vf page work perfectly but On accessing that page through public site datepicker looks very bad

Tags: apex, visualforce

In my org i have a login page with one Date field working as a password for me,
When i access this login page using ....com/apex/Login  that date picker looks good but when i try to access that login page using public site using ..siteURL/login it looks very bad.

Functionality of datepicker is working in both cases it just look am concerned. Firs of all i don't get it, how is this even possible also no clue how to solve this problem,
Date Picker on VF page
[image]
Date Picker on site(same page)
[image]

What should i do to get around this problem.
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: It is the stylesheet not loaded or has conflict what you see in the browser console

Comment: Yes you were right..! i checked my stylesheets which were stored as resource were set to private...Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

In such cases Check all stylesheets refereed in vf page,
In my case i had refereed to a stylesheet which was stored in static resource file but i mistakenly made that static resource private...hence it wasn't loading for public site user.

Thanks to Avijit Chakraborty's prompt reply...I solved this in no time:)